# Implementing a simple, generic thread pool in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread, packaged-task

I want to create a thread pool for experimental purposes (and for the fun factor). It should be able to process a wide variety of tasks (so I can possibly use it in later projects).

---

In my thread pool class I'm going to need some sort of task queue. Since the Standard Library provides `std::packaged_task` since the C++11 standard, my queue will look like `std::deque<std::packaged_task<?()> > task_queue`, so the client can push `std::packaged_task`s into the queue via some sort of public interface function (and then one of the threads in the pool will be notified with a condition variable to execute it, etc.).

---

My question is related to the template argument of the `std::packaged_task<?()>`s in the deque.

The function signature `?()` should be able to deal with any type/number of parameters, because the client can do something like:

`std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(factorial, 342));
thread_pool.add_task(t);`

So I don't have to deal with the type/number of parameters.

But **what should the return value be?** (hence the question mark)

- If I make my whole thread pool class a template class, one instance
  of it will only be able to deal with tasks with a specific signature
  (like `std::packaged_task<int()>`).

  *I want one thread pool object to be able to deal with any kind of task.*
- If I go with `std::packaged_task<void()>` and the function invoked
  returns an integer, or anything at all, then thats undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you can use Boost, then maybe something like [described in this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267138/440558)?

Comment: You can store something like `std::deque<std::function<void()>>`, a list of callables that will wake up threads, run tasks and so on. I think that somewhat more interesting question is *where* and *when* are you going to retrieve the result of the task? You can return a future or expect callbacks, for example.

Comment: @lisyarus, yes, that's what `packaged_task` does, and the OP is already using it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28180524/1774667 -- write a move-only variant of `std::function`.  Args should be bound using a lambda or helper prior to entering the queue.  Retval populates a `future`.  `packaged_task()` returns `void`.  `condition_variable`s for wake up workers.  `std::future` or `std::thread` for worker thread lifetimes.

Comment: it's sounds like not a `thread pool` but `scheduler`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the hard part is that `packaged_task<R()>` is move-only, otherwise you could just toss it into a `std::function<void()>`, and run those in your threads.

There are a few ways around this.

First, ridiculously, use a `packaged_task<void()>` to store a `packaged_task<R()>`.  I'd advise against this, but it does work.  ;)  (what is the signature of `operator()` on `packaged_task<R()>`?  What is the required signature for the objects you pass to `packaged_task<void()>`?)

Second, wrap your `packaged_task<R()>` in a `shared_ptr`, capture that in a lambda with signature `void()`, store that in a `std::function<void()>`, and done.  This has overhead costs, but probably less than the first solution.

Finally, write your own move-only function wrapper.  For the signature `void()` it is short:

```
struct task {
  template<class F,
    class dF=std::decay_t<F>,
    class=decltype( std::declval<dF&>()() )
  >
  task( F&& f ):
    ptr(
      new dF(std::forward<F>(f)),
      [](void* ptr){ delete static_cast<dF*>(ptr); }
    ),
    invoke([](void*ptr){
      (*static_cast<dF*>(ptr))();
    })
  {}
  void operator()()const{
    invoke( ptr.get() );
  }
  task(task&&)=default;
  task&operator=(task&&)=default;
  task()=default;
  ~task()=default;
  explicit operator bool()const{return static_cast<bool>(ptr);}
private:
  std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> ptr;
  void(*invoke)(void*) = nullptr;
};
```

and simple.  The above can store `packaged_task<R()>` for any type `R`, and invoke them later.

This has relatively minimal overhead -- it should be cheaper than `std::function`, at least the implementations I've seen -- except it does not do SBO (small buffer optimization) where it stores small function objects internally instead of on the heap.

You can improve the `unique_ptr<> ptr` container with a small buffer optimization if you want.

Comment: Why is it that the std::packaged_task<void()> version works? I've tried it on 3 different machines with 2 compilers, and it actually does work. But it shouldn't. I mean, that should be undefined behaviour. How did you know that it works fine, and why do you advise against it?

Comment: @krispet `packaged_task<R()>` has an `operator()` woth signature `void()`, because the return value comes out the future, not the `()`.  `packaged_task<void()>` can store any callable, destroyable, movable object that can be invoked with signature `void()`, which includes `packaged_task<R()>`!  Basically packaged task implocitly includes an implementation analogous to my `task` above, a move-only `std::function`.  It has lots of other stuff to, which makes using it that way inefficient.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Do you have a syntax for your second method ? I had a similar question and I wanted different threads or classes to  wrap their work ( function to be called when thread runs ) as an object of that task class which can then be invoked as a callable, with the flexibility to call different functions , taking different parameters and hence a more generic task class which can then be a part of generic thread pool code.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Also in your solution you assigned class T in ptr with value as `new dF(std::forward<F>(f))` is this not expected to be a pointer while declaration of ptr is as `std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> ptr;` taking with T being declared as void but passed a void* as it is a new operation. Or my understanding is wrong here ?

Comment: @Invictus if you want a detailed description, I'd make a post about writing a move only function.  The skeetch I wrote probably has a few glitches, but comments aren't a great place to chat about them.  (And yes, function pointers need to be handled special, because you can't copy a function).

Answer (score 4):

I happen to have an implementation which does exactly that. My way of doing things is to wrap the `std::packaged_task` objects in a struct which abstracts away the return type. The method which submits a task into the thread pool returns a future on the result.

This kind of works, but due to the memory allocations required for each task it is not suitable for tasks which are very short and very frequent (I tried to use it to parallelize chunks of a fluid simulation and the overhead was way too high, in the order of several milliseconds for 324 tasks).

The key part is this structure:

```
struct abstract_packaged_task
{
    template <typename R>
    abstract_packaged_task(std::packaged_task<R> &&task):
        m_task((void*)(new std::packaged_task<R>(std::move(task)))),
        m_call_exec([](abstract_packaged_task *instance)mutable{
            (*(std::packaged_task<R>*)instance->m_task)();
        }),
        m_call_delete([](abstract_packaged_task *instance)mutable{
            delete (std::packaged_task<R>*)(instance->m_task);
        })
    {

    }

    abstract_packaged_task(abstract_packaged_task &&other);

    ~abstract_packaged_task();

    void operator()();

    void *m_task;
    std::function<void(abstract_packaged_task*)> m_call_exec;
    std::function<void(abstract_packaged_task*)> m_call_delete;
};
```

As you can see, it hides away the type dependencies by using lambdas with `std::function` and a `void*`. If you know the maximum size of all possibly occuring `std::packaged_task` objects (I have not checked whether the size has a dependency on `R` at all), you could try to further optimize this by removing the memory allocation.

The submission method into the thread pool then does this:

```
template <typename R>
std::future<R> submit_task(std::packaged_task<R()> &&task)
{
    assert(m_workers.size() > 0);
    std::future<R> result = task.get_future();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex);
        m_task_queue.emplace_back(std::move(task));
    }
    m_queue_wakeup.notify_one();
    return result;
}
```

where `m_task_queue` is an `std::deque` of `abstract_packaged_task` structs. `m_queue_wakeup` is a `std::condition_variable` to wake a worker thread up to pick up the task. The worker threads implementation is as simple as:

```
void ThreadPool::worker_impl()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex, std::defer_lock);
    while (!m_terminated) {
        lock.lock();
        while (m_task_queue.empty()) {
            m_queue_wakeup.wait(lock);
            if (m_terminated) {
                return;
            }
        }
        abstract_packaged_task task(std::move(m_task_queue.front()));
        m_task_queue.pop_front();
        lock.unlock();

        task();
    }
}
```

You can take a look at the full [source code](https://github.com/horazont/scc/blob/7a93301ae04635924d1ddda8f5ea3ee7651d7b73/libffengine-core/src/common/utils.cpp#L99) and the [corresponding header](https://github.com/horazont/scc/blob/7a93301ae04635924d1ddda8f5ea3ee7651d7b73/libffengine-core/ffengine/common/utils.hpp#L77) on my github.

Comment: Take `F&&` instead of `packaged_task`.  Cast to `std::decay<F>::type`.  Replace `void*` with `unique_ptr<void,void(*)(void*)>`, remove dtor and `m_call_delete`.  Replace `m_call_exec` type with `void(*)(abstract_packaged_task*)`.  Result: simpler code, faster code, works on any callable.  Class becomes movable and not copyable.